# How to implement javascript interface with Webview, when using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to implement the `WebAppInterface` (javascript interface for webview) when using Jetpack Compose?

I'm following [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#kotlin)

This is how far I've got so far, but `showToast()` is not called. Adding `@Composable` to `showToast()` didn't help.

```kotlin
/** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
    /** Show a toast from the web page  */
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(toast: String) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String) {
    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(getContext()), "Android")
            loadUrl(urlToRender)
        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(urlToRender)
    })
}
```

HTML/JS code from Android docs:

```html
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed one step in the documentation you refer to:

```kotlin
WebView(context).apply {
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true // <-- This line
    addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(getContext()), "Android")
}
```